# Resultset Validation

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I do have a resultset,which I need to validate only some fields and then update to another table,Really I dont know how to validate it and pass back to the orginal resultset?Is there any way to do it in a better perspective.I do have huge data,so I need to also consider the perfomance

```
while (rs.next()) {
    dataValidation.insertRegDataValidation(rs);

}
```

where the insertRegDataValidation(rs) is method where validation occurs,and if validations returns false,I dont want to update the table,instead of that I want to throw Error,Does any one know any better concepts regarding the same.I never wants to use any frameworks,and to do it in java in an optmized way

Comment: The best concept is to use an appropriate framework or EJB to achieve the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resultset is not huge; you can firstly use ResultSet object to iterate on all resultSet --> do validation on each result --> passing records are put in an ArrayList.

When above iteration finishes ; iterate on this arrayList and you can use same resultSet object to execute inserts..

Other approach can be to use two resultSets. One for Selecting ; while other for all inserts.